# Problems with Bash rename script

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rename

I have a very simple bash script that that I'm running in OSX Terminal. It is designed to rename files using specific file paths. It used to work fine a few months ago but recently all sorts of crazy things happen to it and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
mv() { command mv "$@"; sleep 1; }
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate2.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate2A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate3.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate3A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate4.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate4A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_lifestyle.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_lifestyleA.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_standard.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_standardA.tif
```

I have run it with and without the first line. I added the sleep delay as I suspected what was causing the problems was an over-aggressive IT department disrupting Terminal, which could still be the case, but either way the script does not work.

Here is what Terminal returns when I run it:

```
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate2.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate2A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate3.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Remv -nvest/1140122_alternate3A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate4.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Remv -nTest/1140122_alternate4A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_lifestyle.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Renmv -nv /Volume22_lifestyleA.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_standard.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_standardA.tifç^C^C^C^C^C
```

As you can see it makes a real mess of the file renaming as well as the file paths, which don't even change. I'm literally just adding the letter A between the end of the filename and the file extension.

Does anyone see anything here that could be causing this to happen? Our IT department has started using a content gateway called WebSense recently to monitor company activity, is it possible that it is causing the problems?

Comment: Is there any danger that your script has been near a Windows machine, or otherwise been contaminated with carriage return (^M) characters?  I'm not sure that would explain what you see easily, but just wondering.  How do you run it?  `sh script.sh`? Have you tried `bash -x script.sh` (or `sh -x script.sh`)?

Comment: Yes it's definitely been near a Windows machine. The file paths have to be searched for in Windows because we do not yet have a setup for proper communication between our Windows server and our Macs. Those file paths are put into an Excel document that I then format in TextWrangler to be used in the code. But, it's quite possible it's making a mess of things. I should also try running it in a shell and not directly in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us (yet) *how* you invoke your script.

If your script were still recognized as an *executable*, it would not produce the output you state - it wouldn't just *echo* your script, additional trailing characters notwithstanding.

- If you're invoking your script *directly*:

  - Does you script have a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang%20%28Unix%29), as the script below?
  - Has it been marked as *executable*, with `chmod +x <file>`?
- Otherwise: What executable are you passing it to?
- Does your script contain unexpected characters, which show with prefix `^` (such as `^M` for CR (`\r`) chars.) or `M-` if you run `LC_ALL=C cat -et <file>`, as [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggests?
- As Jonathan further suggests: are you perhaps invoking your *script as a whole* with `sh -nv <file>` or `bash -nv <file>`, which would at least explain why the *source code* is printed (`-v`) *without executing* the script (`-n`), though it doesn't per se explain the unexpected trailing characters.

In the meantime, here's a reformulation of your script in the spirit of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t%20repeat%20yourself):

```
#!/bin/bash

pathPrefix='/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122'

files=(
  "${pathPrefix}_alternate1.tif"
  "${pathPrefix}_alternate2.tif"
  "${pathPrefix}_alternate3.tif"
  "${pathPrefix}_alternate4.tif"
  "${pathPrefix}_lifestyle.tif"
  "${pathPrefix}_standard.tif"
)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  mv -nv "$file" "${file%.tif}a.tif" 
done
```

Comment: Note that on macOS, the `mv` command has the `-v` option which is described as:  _`-v` Cause `mv` to be verbose, showing files after they are moved._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but that causes the following type of output, quite distinct from the source code: `foo -> bar`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That sounds very plausible (except for the funky trailing characters) - I've added your guess to the answer - let's see what the OP comes back with.

Comment: Yeah this is actually a more complicated usage I guess than I had realized. So first, I am pasting the code straight into the command line of Terminal. I'm not executing it through a shell. Second, the file paths are given to me in an Excel sheet that is generated in Windows. I copy/paste the paths into TextWrangler and format it in there. I replace all the spaces and things like that, but perhaps that is causing the problem? There are hidden carriage returns etc somewhere?

Comment: @JamesTrory: Incredibly, in this day and age, it seems that Excel on macOS still uses Mac OS Classic CR-only line breaks (`\r`, represented in caret notation as `^M`). However, when you paste into Terminal.app, these are usually converted to Unix-style LF-only line breaks. Pasting into Terminal.app _is_ executing through a shell (`bash`, by default), just an _interactive_ one. To examine what you're pasting, save the TextWrangler buffer to a file and run `LC_ALL=C cat -et <file>`. I still have no explanation for your overall symptoms.

Comment: @JamesTrory: In the future, to save time, please include all relevant information (which includes the method of invocation) _in your question_, _from the beginning_. Generally, it is most helpful to craft an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).